# locate and uninstall DynamoDB Local

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, local, uninstallation

I haphazardly attempted to install DynamoDB Local a number of times via the instructions listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html). I'm unsure where it installed.

I'd like to locate where I've installed the database, and/or uninstall it completely. There seem to be plenty of discussions throughout the web discussing how to run/install/use DynamoDB, but I can't find material describing how to remove it. Any resources or ideas would be much appreciated.

Note: I'm using OS 10.12.4

Comment: Actually, the `ps` output shows that **no dynamoDb is running**, `grep dynamo` is a part of your command

Comment: @xtx Ah that explains the timestamps too. Do you know if there is a way to determine where or if it is still installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those instructions tell you how to download DynamoDB. There is no other installation procedure necessary. Therefore, if you delete the unzipped folder that contains DynamoDB Local, you have deleted DynamoDB Local. You can restart your computer to make sure there are no lingering DynamoDB Local processes. On Mac OS X, you could issue `find / | grep DynamoDBLocal` to look for other copies.